# Dataflow job repeatedly stops VM's after CPU utilization reaches ~100% and starts another one instead of working in parallel

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a batch Dataflow job which reads some columns from Bigquery, convert them to beam.Row format and then applies a SqlTransform for each column in parallel. I set the number of workers between 1 and 5.

I do not know why the job starts only one VM and the CPU reach above 80% utilization, then it stops the VM and opens another one. This pattern repeats until the last SqlTransform is executed.
I tried to add a reshuffle step after the conversion to beam.Row in order to prevent fusion but the problem persists.
What shall I do to optimize the pipeline?
[Update]: I suspect that the throughput is not enough to trigger the creation of a new VM in parallel while the active VM CPU utilization reaches 100%.

Here are the graphs:
[image: VM stop and start new one]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The VM is most likely being terminated because it is unhealthy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The VM had minimum resources (one core + 3.75 Gb RAM) and the machine was freezing before the autoscaling could kick in. Once I set the job to use 2xcores and double the RAM size, the auto-scaling worked.